# Editing a post and giving the title textbox focus

Tags: discussion, edits

I tried to edit a post and before the whole page had loaded I clicked within the post body and started typing away.

Once the page had fully loaded the cursor jumped to the title textbox and I accidentally replaced the title with what I was typing.

Can the focus only be changed to the title if it isn't anywhere else (i.e. in the post content editor box)?

Comment: I agree. I've made the title go boom too many times. Note that I prefer this for _only_ editing. Titles are the first thing you should add while _creating_ a post, due to the dupechecker.